# How to get the value of DataNavigateUrlFields?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, hyperlink

I have a DataTable and it is passing a value though a `DataNavigateUrlField`.

In code what do I type to get that value, e.g.:

```
MessageNum = DataNavigateUrlField[MessageNumber];
```

Here i have `DataNavigateUrlFields="MessageNumber"`, What in my C# Code can i do to get the value of MessageNumber?? Please i need help.

```
<asp:HyperLinkField
    HeaderText="Subject"
    DataNavigateUrlFields="MessageNumber" 
    DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/ViewMailContent.aspx?MessageNumber={0}"
    DataTextField="Subject" />
```

The DataTable is set as a GridView.DataSource, and then sent to a page, the user selects a hyperlink and then the page navigates, i need the message number selected.

I noticed The Value is showing on the top of my Screen in the Url and its the correct value, but how do i get the value, and is it possible to get the value before the Page navigates? else The page will have to load twice i think.

I started web about a week ago so not give me extreme web lingo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have (at least) two options:

1. If you need the value in the destination page (the page that you navigate to by clicking the url in the grid) you'll just write

   Example (in code behind):

   ```
   Request.QueryString("MessageNumber")
   ```
2. If you need the value in the page that has the grid you'll rewrite the url to point to a javascript function, which in turn may redirect to the destination page.

   ```
   <asp:HyperLinkField
       HeaderText="Subject"
       DataNavigateUrlFields="MessageNumber" 
       DataNavigateUrlFormatString="javascript:myFunction({0})"
       DataTextField="Subject" />
   ```

   The function (should be in a javascript block in source page):

   ```
   function myFunction(id)
   { 
       alert("Now you are leaving this page");
       document.location = "ViewMailContent.aspx?MessageNumber=" + id;
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks the Request.QueryString("MessageNumber") Worked Perfectly fine, Is the any way i can call? Request.QueryString("MessageNumber") from a web service?

Comment: You may call Request.QueryString from a web service but it depends on how the webservice is set up. But redirecting from a grid to a web service (if that is what you want to do...) seems to make little sense. Can you tell us more about what you want to do and maybe we could suggest an alternative solution?